# Roslyn : How to check data dependence between statements?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am using Roslyn to deal with C# code. 
I want to check whether two statements have data dependence, data dependence means :

say if I have called f(),g(),h().

```
int x = 10, y = 20, z =30;
f(x);
g(x, y);
h(y);
```

statement "f(x);" have data dependence with "g(x, y);" because they share the same variable x directly.

Can I achieve this by SemanticModel and Symbol.Equals?

by the way, there are classes such as "LabeledStatementSyntax" or "CheckedStatementSyntax", I have no idea what they are!! Where could I find some reference?

Comment: If you want to know what an *XSyntax* is, go look in [the spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx) for *X*. for example, *labeled-statement* is defined as "*identifier* **:** *statement*" and *checked-statement* as "**checked** *block*".

Comment: I don't think `f(x)` and `g(x, y)` should be considered to have data dependency, because what `f(x)` does won't affect the behavior of `g(x, y)`; `f(x)` can't modify `x`.